# aws crawler not creating awsdatacatalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue-data-catalog

After using an aws crawler, when querying athena I get the following error...
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:15: Table awsdatacatalog.datahub2.datahub2 does not exist

I've tried creating a new crawler, a new DB and table.  The only thing not changing is the data but this was fine when the crawler ran 2 weeks ago.

Name    Conversations3
Description 
Create a single schema for each S3 path false
Security configuration

### Tags

State   Ready
Schedule
Last updated    Mon May 20 15:07:07 GMT+100 2019
Date created    Mon May 20 15:07:07 GMT+100 2019
Database    datahub2
Service role    service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole-datahub
Selected classifiers
Data store  S3
Include path    s3://s3-itso-transithub-datastreams/retailerConversation/temp/10
Exclude patterns
Configuration options
Schema updates in the data store    Update the table definition in the data catalog.
Object deletion in the data store   Mark the table as deprecated in the data catalog.

Before 2 weeks ago this crawler was creating a table that could be queried in athena without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Referencing table names by s3Bucketname.tablename solved the problem for me.